# Do long running process with Task and showing Exception if there is one

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am testing for using Task in my application.
Now, I have done the fallowing:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
   // long running process
   throw new Exception("test"); // throwing TestException
});
task.ContinueWith(x => MyErrorHandler(task.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

void MyErrorHandler(Exception error) {
   MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
}
```

The idea is, that the long running process will executed and the user can working on without any blocking of the UI. If there was a problem (exception) it will be show, after the long running process has finished (in the normal case, there would be no exception)

Is this the correct way I have used it or does I have to do it on another way? Are there any problems, which I can get on this way and I don't see now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work, as you're explicitly checking `Task.Exception`, which will prevent the exception from being unobserved.

I would make a couple of recommendations here.

First, if this is truly a long running task, you might want to specify that:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
   // long running process
   throw new Exception("test"); // throwing TestException
}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Second, you don't need the closure over `task`:

```
// use x.Exception, since x is the task
task.ContinueWith(x => MyErrorHandler(x.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

You may also want to have this run on the main thread, especially if you decide you want to use something more elaborate (in your UI) for reporting:

```
// This will work if MyErrorHandler uses a UI control, since it'll marshal back to the current synchronization context
task.ContinueWith(x => MyErrorHandler(x.Exception), 
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

(This is only required if you're going to use UI controls, etc, in your error handler.)

Also - If you're using .NET 4.5 or the async targetting pack for .NET 4, you can simplify this by using the new `async`/`await` support.  If you flag your method as `async`, you can do:

```
try
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
           // long running process
           throw new Exception("test"); // throwing TestException
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
catch(Exception error)
{
      MyErrorHandler(error);
}
```

Comment: Hi Reed - Thank you very much for your explanation. Can you also explain me, what is 'TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning' doing? I am now also searching for a nice solution to prevent the User to close the application while the task is running and showing a progress-wheel in the GUI StatusBar when the task start and hiding it when the task has ended. Perhaps do you have some hints about that for me?

Comment: @ThomasKehl THe LongRunning hint, with the default scheduler, causes it to make a dedicated thread for the task.  As for the progress wheel - just turn it on when you start the task, and add a continuation to turn it off (though, again, this is easier with the async/await support)

Comment: when I try the solution with await I will get the errormessage "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'." Can you help me, what I have to change for using this?

Comment: @ThomasKehl You need to flag your method as async - for example, if it's `void Foo()` make it `private async void Foo()`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is working. Perhaps there is a nice and simple way to prevent the user to close the application, when a Task is running?

Comment: @ThomasKehl Pretty much just have to have a flag or somethign, and stop the app from closing as normal.

Comment: @ReedCopsey - Is there a way to propagate the exceptions to UI thread? I would like to MyErrorHandler to propagate exception to the UI thread that invoked this task.